# How to migrate one type of contents to other type having same fields?

Tags: 8, nodes, migrations

I have 2 content types having same fields and I have many contents added by cleint in both the types,now I want to change some of the node's type A  other type..
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Too many options. Programmatically. Migration. Feeds. REST. But what have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably prepare a view that filters the nodes that you want to migrate using  [Rest Export display](http://redcrackle.com/blog/rest-export-views-drupal-8) and than create a migration to import the previous Export as described in [this tutorial](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/pull-content-from-a-remote-drupal-8-site-using-migrate-and-json-api)